# Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: XXXXXX"

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

Facing this issue while archiving the project.

```
/Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-nprspddadaohcot/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Projectname.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib: code object is not signed at all
```

`error: Failed with exit code 1 (in target 'xxxx' from project 'xxxx').`

I've added the developer account to Xcode and downloaded the manual profile also.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to Clean the Build Folder first (Product -> Clean Build Folder).
If that fails, make sure you have properly set up the signing in Xcode.
You can change those settings by clicking on the name of your project in the Files viewer on the left side of Xcode, then navigate to the second tab called "Signing & Capabilities".

It should be set to "Automatically manage signing", the Team should be your Apple ID, and there should be no errors there. If there is, there's something wrong with your developer account or the Keychain.